# Is it possible to update manuals on MacOS

Tags: osx, man

I was doing some research on some C functions, and I noticed when I used, for example, `man fgets`, it outputs the manual for the `fgets` function; however, it references ISO C99 which is out-of-date compared to ISO C11. Is it possible to update manuals within terminal, not just particularly C manuals?

Comment: The manuals describe what Apple's delivered.  (If you use an add-on such as MacPorts or brew, those in turn would install their own documentation).

Answer (score 1):

The neat things with manuals that are installed on your system is that they describe what's installed on the system.

If the base system compiler is a C89 or C99 C compiler, then this will be reflected by the installed manuals of the standard C library functions.

Installing a package which enables a C11 compiler will likely also install the C runtime libraries, utilities, and documentation to go with them.  These new manual pages may be available in an alternative path compared to the base system manuals.

See the `SEARCH PATH FOR MANUAL PAGES` section in the `man` manual for how to modify the search path for manual pages, and then figure out where the new manuals are installed (this will differ depending on how you installed the compiler and related things).